# USE database_name command alternative for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

what is the alternative of

```
use database_name
```

command of SQL server in oracle?

Comment: Not sure, but I think [`SET`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html)

Comment: A "database" in Oracle is something ***completely*** different than a "database" in SQL Server. As the closest match of a SQL Server "database" is a *schema* in Oracle, the equivalent statement would be `alter session set current_schema = new_schema_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative would be `alter session` statement:

```
alter session set current_schema=<<schema_name>>
```

The one of the main differences is it will only change schema qualifier when a qualifier is omitted in the select statement, for example. For instance, if you logged in as `user1` and executed the above `alter session` statement specifying `user2` as current_schema then the `user2` will be used as schema qualifier and not the `user1`. And unlike SQL Server's `use` statement, Oracle's original session will retain its privileges and wont acquire new one after the execution of `alter session` statement.

In order to be able to select(for example) from a table that resides in the `user2` schema, `user1` will have to have `select on` that table or `select any table` privilege. Same goes for any other object, if there is no privilege to operate on that object, statement that references that object will fail.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I don't have alter access. Is there any way I can do this without alter command? I don't want to qualify my table name with the schema name.

Comment: @user2617588 Firstly. This operation does not require `alter session` system privilege. Secondly. `Is there any way I can do this without alter command?` I'm not aware of what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe you do not need to do it at all just because you got used to do it in SQL server. As an alternative to reference objects in another schema you could [create synonyms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm)(will require `create synonym` system) for that objects `create synonym <<synonym_name>> for <<schema_name>>.<<object_name>>` - would be safer.